# Set custom headers for WebClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I have a webclient that I want to connect with multiple vendors.

Apart from the uri and the data, there's also the headers to consider, as they can differ from vendor to vendor. Surrounding the client, I have a lot of otherstuff - so I want to write this code once.

So, I'm trying to create a base method that has all the main functionality - something like the example below - that will allow me to fill in the blanks from the calling function.

```
    public string Post()
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new CustomWebClient();

            return client.UploadString("", "");
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Status)
            {
                case WebExceptionStatus.Timeout:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Obviously it's easy to pass in address and data as parameters, but how can I set the headers using `client.Headers.Add()` or something?

I'm struggling to come up with a pattern that works and doesn't smell.

Comment: You can `client.Headers.Add("test", "test");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the method Post() is a public method of the CustomWebClient, it would be a good design to set all the required properties for the method post via property setters or constructor initialization.

```
public class CustomWebClient
{
    public NameValueCollection Headers
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public CustomWebClient()
    {
       this.Headers = new NameValueCollection();
    }

    //Overload the constructor based on your requirement.

    public string Post()
    {
      //Perform the post or UploadString with custom logic
    }    

    //Overload the method Post for passing various parameters like the Url(if required)
}
```

In the place where the CustomWebClient is being used,

```
using (CustomWebClient client = new CustomWebClient())
{   
     client.Headers.Add("HeaderName","Value");
     client.Post();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of possible headers is limited, you can declare them as `public enum` in your `CustomWebClient` class and create an overload of either the `constructor` or the `UploadString()` function (whichever one you like) and pass it the value of the `enum` to set the header accordingly. Example:

```
public class CustomWebClient {
    public enum Headers { StandardForm, Json, Xml }

    public CustomWebClient() {
    }

    //This is your original UploadString.
    public string UploadString(string x, string y) {
        //Call the overload with default header.
        UploadString("...", "...", Headers.StandardForm);
    }    


    //This is the overloaded UploadString.
    public string UploadString(string x, string y, Headers header) {
       switch(header){
       case Headers.StandardForm:
           client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           break;
       case Headers.Json:
           client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","text/json");
           break;
       case Headers.Xml:
           client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","text/xml");
           break;
       }
       //Continue your code.
    }    
}
```

The most appealing benefits of using an `enum` is eliminating the possible typos and giving you intelli-sense so you don't need to remember what your options are.